# Organizing web MVVM file content and structure

Tags: javascript, html, web, mvvm, kendo-ui

After considering this for quite some time, I was wondering what you guys thought about it or whether there might already be a known pattern to be used in such cases.

Let's just say for the sake of argument that I'm using C# MVC with Kendo UI (or JQuery).

As I see it, the client code is made up of 3 parts:

1. markup - HTML.
2. declarative JavaScript - Kendo UI/JQuery controls.
3. view model - the MVVM model.

I think these parts should be separated as follows:

I want the view models to interact with each other so I would declare all view models in separate js files and load them upfront.

The declarative javascript is useless without its markup so it should either be
put it in the same html file or separated in another js file, to be loaded at the end of the markup (or by using the document ready event).

So at the end of the day I'd have:

product.html

```
    <ul id="example">
       <li><label>Product Name</label><input type="text"></li>
       <li><label>Product Size</label><input id="product-size" data-bind="value:selectedSize></li>
    </ul>
<script src="product.js"></script>
```

product.js

```
kendo.bind($("#example"), viewModel);

$("#product-size").kendoDropDownList({
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        dataSource: data,
                        index: 0,
                        change: onChange
                    });
```

product.model.js

```
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        selectedSize: null,
};
```

Comment: 100 components = 100 js files? Goes against most best practices of trying to minimize requests especially when they are intertwined with html views

Comment: you can load all view model files upfront with MVC bundle  .

Comment: meaning only one server request. no one has something else to add?

Comment: Question is actually off topic for SO as it falls into category of `opinion based`

Comment: Off topic? we are discussing about implementation\best practice for relatively new architecture pattern, the MVVM. My humble experience led me to this conclusion, I think its a very legit discussion to share insights.

Comment: Well then you should probably read the section in help on `what not to ask`. There are other sites in stackexchange network that are more appropriate

Comment: just ignore this guy, he's a troll